# HQL - Left Outer Join - Path expected for join

Tags: hibernate

I would like to join a table with another in JQL.

My first class :

```
public class Order implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "CDT_ID", insertable = true, nullable = true, updatable = true)
    private String idCDT;
    ...
    }
}
```

My second class :

```
public class UserInfo implements Serializable {

    private String idCDT;
        private String name;
}
```

I would like to get all the orders sort by the name of the employees.

I have tried this query in HQL:

```
SELECT  order FROM  Order order 
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserInfo employee WITH employee.idCDT=order.idCDT   
WHERE order.year = 2014 
ORDER BY employee.name ASC
```

But i got the following error : Path expected for join!

My question is : is it possible to join two tables in HQL with JOIN if my object Order doesn't have an attribute UserInfo? If it's possible, how can i implement it?
I am obliged to use a "left outer join" because the employee can be null.

Could you help me, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, path is required for left join, if you do not need left join, then you can use the implicit join in this case like below.

```
SELECT  order FROM  Order order, 
UserInfo employee where employee.idCDT=order.idCDT   
and order.year = 2014 
ORDER BY employee.name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. You need an association between Order and UserInfo to be able to do a left join.

Comment: OK. So i will add an association between Order and UserInfo if the answer of Zeus doesn't work. Thank you.